# modify plugin to support RTL

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I've developed a plugin and now I want to make it RTL compatible. Does anybody know how to determine is RTL enabled in admin panel or not?
Or maybe somebody knows any CSS tips for RTL support?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for the function `is_rtl()`.

Have a look in de codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_rtl